# SIMtrix/Simplis Simulator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, simulation, buck

I'd like to use SIMtrix/Simplis Simulator for simulation of SMPS design, and I'm about to start building a peak current mode buck converter like the one shown below from richtek.com:
[image]

but unfortunately I did not find the current sensor device, please does anyone used this software and know where I can find this component in order to continue my simulation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sensor you talk about is a simple current-controlled voltage source. You can place it by invoking >place>controlled sources>Current Controlled Voltage source:

[image]

However, if it does the job of sensing the current, I prefer to resort to a current-controlled current source (press F) that I direct to a 1-ohm resistance. That way, I can easily add another current source which compensates the sub-harmonic poles:

[image]

\$k_r\$ and \$k_i\$ are parameters you can pass using a .VAR statement placed in the control window that you invoke pressing F11:

.VAR kr=0.05

.VAR ri=200m

as an example.

Finally, please note that this current-controlled voltage or current source plays the role of a current-sense transformer (without the magnetic environment of course) and does not provide damping as a normal sense resistor would do.